# Need to edit title bar of putty through vba code

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

I am using the below vba code to open a putty screen on a button click.

```
TaskID = Shell("C:\putty.exe 173.194.127.210", vbMaximizedFocus)
```

When it opens a new screen, the title bar will contain the string "173.194.127.210 - PUTTY". 
I want to change "173.194.127.210 - PUTTY" to "173.194.127.210 - HELLO" through vba code when the above code opens a new screen. Can anyone share the code for doing this?
Please note that I am not using super putty.

I am able to do the same manually with following steps:

1. Right click on title bar of putty screen opened.
2. Click on change settings
3. Click on Behavior under the option Window
4. Change window title as 173.194.127.210 - HELLO

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change this value via the command line. The only place that this value can be set is in a session. Look at the PuTTY Configuration page, and click on the Session branch to see this. There is always a session called "Default Settings" which can't be deleted, and simply shows the application's internal defaults. You can't change these. However, you can create a new session programatically, save the window title in that, and then use the "-load" option of the PuTTY command line to load that session when starting the application.

This information for sessions is stored in the registry for each user, under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions key. Each key under here becomes a session with the name of the key. For the purposes of creating a session name which is unlikely to clash with a user's session, the code below uses a name which is the application EXE name, prefixed by two underscores.

The registry value you need to write for the window title is "WinTitle". However, you must also provide the "HostName", "Protocol" and "Port" values for PuTTY to open correctly. All values except "Port" are string (REG_SZ), whilst "Port" is an integer (REG_DWORD).

```
Option Explicit

Private Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER As Long = &H80000001

Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS     As Long = 0&

Private Const REG_SZ            As Long = 1
Private Const REG_DWORD         As Long = 4

Private Enum REGSAM
    KEY_ALL_ACCESS = &HF003F
    KEY_CREATE_LINK = &H20
    KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = &H4
    KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = &H8
    KEY_EXECUTE = &H20019
    KEY_NOTIFY = &H10
    KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1
    KEY_READ = &H20019
    KEY_SET_VALUE = &H2
    KEY_WOW64_32KEY = &H200
    KEY_WOW64_64KEY = &H100
    KEY_WRITE = &H20006
End Enum

Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "Advapi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function RegCreateKeyEx Lib "Advapi32.dll" Alias "RegCreateKeyExW" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long, _
    ByVal lpSubKey As Long, _
    ByVal Reserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpClass As Long, _
    ByVal dwOptions As Long, _
    ByVal samDesired As REGSAM, _
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
    ByRef phkResult As Long, _
    ByRef lpdwDisposition As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function RegSetValueEx Lib "Advapi32.dll" Alias "RegSetValueExW" ( _
    ByVal hKey As Long, _
    ByVal lpValueName As Long, _
    ByVal Reserved As Long, _
    ByVal dwType As Long, _
    ByVal lpData As Long, _
    ByVal cbData As Long _
) As Long

Private Enum ConnectionType
    Raw
    Telnet
    Rlogin
    SSH
End Enum

Private Function OpenPutty(ByRef the_sHost As String, ByRef the_sTitle As String, ByVal enmConnectionType As ConnectionType, Optional ByVal the_nPort = -1) As Long

    Dim sUniqueSession                  As String
    Dim sKeyUniqueSession               As String
    Dim sConnectionType                 As String
    Dim nPort                           As Long
    Dim hKeyUniqueSession               As Long

    sUniqueSession = "__" & App.EXEName
    sKeyUniqueSession = "Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\" & sUniqueSession

    ' Provide the connection type / protocol string, and a default port value.
    Select Case enmConnectionType
    Case Raw
        sConnectionType = "raw"
        nPort = -1
    Case Telnet
        sConnectionType = "telnet"
        nPort = 23
    Case Rlogin
        sConnectionType = "rlogin"
        nPort = 513
    Case SSH
        sConnectionType = "ssh"
        nPort = 22
    End Select

    ' -1 indicates use the default port value.
    If the_nPort <> -1 Then
        nPort = the_nPort
    End If

    If RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, StrPtr(sKeyUniqueSession), 0&, 0&, 0&, KEY_SET_VALUE, 0&, hKeyUniqueSession, 0&) = ERROR_SUCCESS Then
        RegSetValueEx hKeyUniqueSession, StrPtr("HostName"), 0&, REG_SZ, StrPtr(the_sHost), LenB(the_sHost)
        RegSetValueEx hKeyUniqueSession, StrPtr("WinTitle"), 0&, REG_SZ, StrPtr(the_sTitle), LenB(the_sTitle)
        RegSetValueEx hKeyUniqueSession, StrPtr("Protocol"), 0&, REG_SZ, StrPtr(sConnectionType), LenB(sConnectionType)
        RegSetValueEx hKeyUniqueSession, StrPtr("PortNumber"), 0&, REG_DWORD, VarPtr(nPort), LenB(nPort)
        RegCloseKey hKeyUniqueSession
    End If

    OpenPutty = Shell(App.Path & "\putty.exe -load """ & sUniqueSession & """", vbMaximizedFocus)

End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    OpenPutty "192.168.1.5", "My custom title", Telnet
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!!! This code is amazing and working fine. The line    sUniqueSession = "__" & App.EXEName needs to change if it is throwing error. It seems we can add any string on behalf of App.EXEName.

Comment: Can anyone share vba code to change the "Lines of scroll back" from 200 to 200000.  Manually we can achieve this by following steps. 1) Right click on title bar of putty screen. 2)Click on change settings 3) Click on window 4) Change lines of scroll back from 200 to 200000 5) Click on apply.

Comment: @user3424922 Yes, you can use any string. As I said, I was just creating a string which is unlikely to conflict with a user's session name. As for other values - you now have all the tools you need to set anything appearing in the configuration screen. Do what I did: change settings manually, and save them as a session. Use the REGEDIT.EXE program to look up the values in the new registry key. Search for your data under the key, and you will find the value name. There should only be two types of values, REG_DWORD and REG_SZ. Use my existing code to see how you write these types of values.

Comment: Does anyone know why despite the code being indented correctly, it is coming out all left justified?

Comment: @user3424922 Does this answer your question properly?

Comment: Hi Mark, No doubt that the code you had written is working fine. Thanks a lot - Dominic

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (and generally should, since presumably if you accept an answer then you found it useful).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Sub Main()
    On Error Resume Next
    hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Microsoft Works Calendar")
    Ret = SetWindowText(hwindows, "Calandar")
End Sub
```